Shapefile class is not coming arcgis pro sdk c#
I have added below namespaces though the Shapefile class is not coming in arcgis pro sdk c# code in ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Controls.ProWindow
name spaces are
using ArcGIS.Core.Data;
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Core;
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

and code failed is
using (Shapefile shapefile = new Shapefile(shapefilePath))
        {
        }

Error i am getting as below
The type or namespace name 'Shapefile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
